# Does $f_n \to f$ imply $|f_n|\to |f|$

Tags: real-analysis

Generally, if a sequence of measurable functions $f_n$ (not necessarily nonnegative) converges to $f$ a.e, on a set $E$,  $f_n \to f$.  Does it  imply $|f_n|\to |f|$

Comment: Yes, the implication holds (in the sense that $|f_n|\to |f|$ a.e.). It follows immediately from the continuity of $|\cdot|$.

Comment: Can you think of an inequality that relates $\big| |f_n|-|f|\big|$ to $|f_n-f|$?  (Also, I assume you mean a.e. for this as well.)

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis, Honestly I though this is something I should know but for some reason I had nothing.

Comment: @YousufSoliman thank you

Comment: @MPW, Yes, someone just wrote that in the solution below. Reverse triangle Inequality. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the reverse triangle inequality, namely
$$
\lvert\lvert x\rvert-\lvert y\rvert\rvert
\leq\lvert
x-y
\rvert.
$$
for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. More generally, if $g$ is a continuous function and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f$ pointwise (respectively, a.e.), then $(g\circ f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $g\circ f$ pointwise (respectively, a.e.). This comes down to the fact that continuous functions play nicely with limits: specifically, that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=a\implies \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(a_n)=g(a)$$ when $g$ is continuous (apply this to the question above "point-by-point").

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because $$|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|; \quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$

However, the other way round may not be true. Try to find a counterexample :)